# What is definition of "adversary"? And what do they do?

Tags: secret-sharing, attack, terminology

Currently I am writing my last assignment about secret sharing. But I don't clearly understand *adversary*. I know this is a fundamental concept in secret sharing. But I couldn't find references that clearly definite *adversary*. Moreover, what is passive attack and active attack? What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formally, an **adversary** is simply a (probabilistic) algorithm, which we usually assume to run in polynomial time in $n$, the [security parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_parameter).
From a more intuitive point of view, an *adversary* is the model of an attacker on the real life, since every attacker follows an strategy that boils down to an algorithm.

Now, at a high level, a *passive attack* is an attack where the adversary simply "sees" the information (encrypted data, signatures, etc.) and try to find the secret data from the information gathered. By contrast, in an *active attack*, the adversary has the ability to "interact" somehow (for instance, by encrypting messages of his choice or even decrypting messages of his choice).

Of course, each one of these notions has its formalization (e.g. [Computational indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_indistinguishability), [CPA-security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack), [CCA-security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-ciphertext_attack)).

Comment: It might help to say that informally, the adversary is the bad guy. In secret sharing s/he might have a variety of goals, like guessing the secret, or preventing reconstruction of the right secret. The formal adversary in the question is a model of the informal one, and the tools s/he might use.